# ParserError: Expected identifier, got 'LParen' constructor() public {

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

i don't know why i get this problem, anybody who can helps thanks a lot

pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract MathContract {
    function mulAtoB(uint a, uint b) pure public returns(uint) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

Error parsing /Users/yuwei/Desktop/1110/demo1/abcd/contracts/Migrations.sol: ParsedContract.sol:7:14: ParserError: Expected identifier, got 'LParen'
  constructor() public {

YuweideMacBook-Air:abcd yuwei$ truffle version
Truffle v4.1.4 (core: 4.1.4)
Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works just fine, assuming you have the right compiler version.

To verify, you can just copy+paste the code in Remix https://remix.ethereum.org and change the first line to be `pragma solidity ^0.5.1;` as that's the default compiler in Remix (I think).

Comment: no,  there is the same error

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works just fine for me, too.
But the problem is in your `Migrations` contract. When using Truffle you should leave as it is was created by `truffle init` command, because it is required for proper Truffle work.